# Call and append new values to new rows using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have already loaded data to the first table row using jQuery-ajax but when I add new rows, it's all the same data loaded in the first row. How can I add new data/values to new rows?

Here is my jQuery Ajax code:

```
//Table Add New Row
         


    addNewRow();
    $("#add").click(function() {
      addNewRow();
    })

    function addNewRow() {
      var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/load',
        method: "GET",
        //data : {getNewOrderItem:1},

        success: function(data) {

          $("#brand").append(data);
          var n = 0;
          $(".number").each(function() {
            $(this).html(++n);
          });
        }
      })
    }
    $("#remove").click(function() {
      $("#brand").children("tr:last").remove();
      calculate(0, 0);
    });
```

This is my html code:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">No</th>
          <th scope="col">Inventory </th>
          <th scope="col">Product </th>
          <th scope="col"> Qty in Inventory </th>
          <th scope="col">Unit</th>
          <th scope="col">Unit Price </th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Price </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="brand">
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[You can see a preview image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhYy5.png)

Comment: you need to share your HTML too

Comment: Html code added

Comment: What is the content of `data`? What is returned by the AJAX call?

Comment: in `url : '/load'` where is `.extension`?

Comment: data is already fetched from the database: `Object { 38: "323", 39: "df", 43: "aaa" }`

Comment: there is no any extension in laravel @KUMAR

Comment: @kst so you have to also mention `laravel Tag` in this question for more users reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try being more specific:

```js
$("#brand").append(
    `<tr>
        <td>${data.something}</td>
        <td>${data.somethingelse}</td>
        ... for each of your columns
    </tr>`);
```

Do this for each of the rows in your dataset

Comment: I have already fetched the data and appended like the following, only for one row:
`jQuery('select[name="price[]"]').empty();                   
                       jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                          $('select[name="price[]"]').append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ value +'</option>'); 
});`

Comment: you can replace `jQuery` with `$`

Comment: I did but still same data in all new added rows.

Comment: What do you mean by added rows? Rows you add by clicking your `#add`? New data from your ajax? As for `#add`, you don't seem to have any element with `#add` in your html. Is this the full code?

Comment: Thanks @Epic it worked! but how to get those appended values in order to store in database?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a backend that is connected to a database somehow. You could send a post request with the jquery `$.post()` function. I suggest you look it up to find out how.